# Sanitizing JSON data for usage as JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, php, json, security, sanitization

I'm going to be dynamically generating a `JSON` file which is then passed to [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) as the `emoticons` object; this data will come from the database, so essentially it *should* be safe, but one can never be 100% sure.

This is how it is being called:

```
// Create var to store emoticons
var emoticons = false;

$.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json')
.done(function(response) {
    emoticons = response;
    console.log(emoticons);
})
.always(function() {
    // always initialize sceditor
    $(".sceditor").sceditor({
        // Other options.....
        plugins: "bbcode",
        emoticons: emoticons,
    });
});
```

An example of the `JSON` file would look like:

```
{
    "dropdown": {
        ":)": "smile.png",
        ":angel:": "angel.png",
        ":angry:": "angry.png",
        "8-)": "cool.png",
        ":'(": "cwy.png",
    }
}
```

So the emoticon code and filename are pulled from the database. Is there anything I need to do here other than escape double quotes? Whilst this data will be coming from the database, it's possible the codes/filenames will be provided by the user.

When I store them in the database I will be stripping tags with `PHP's` `strip_tags` function.

I wanted to avoid turning the data into `html entities` as it doesn't seem to play nice with the editor as it doesn't turn the emoticons into smileys within the editor if you say set the code as `:&quot;)` - it will literally output in the editor as `:")` rather than show the smiley.

**Edit:** To see an example of how the code is used check out the [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) demo. Only difference is the demo uses the default codes provided within the JS file itself and mine will be provided via a `JSON` file passed as an option.

What is are my best options here?

Comment: `json_encode()` will escape the double quotes for you, you don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: Anything else depends on precisely how you're going to be using them. If you show code and the desired effect, we may be able to advise.

Comment: Please post your code here, not a link to a third-party site.

Comment: @Barmar That is the best way to see how it is being used, that's all I can say. Unless you want to see how I am calling it.

Comment: It might be the best way to see it today. What if they change the demo next year? Your question should be self-contained so future readers will understand precisely what you're asking about.

Comment: @Barmar Well I can't really embed the editor here can I? Best I can do is a jsfiddle, but that again is a 3rd-party site.

Comment: Not the editor, your code that uses it, and passes the JSON data as an option. I don't even see anything about emoticons on the page you linked to -- I guess you mean we have to drill down into the documentation.

Comment: Ok done. As for the page, you can see the little smiley face on the editor on the right hand side.